# Unexpected output of 5 binary A's using join

Tags: python

```
seq = b'A'
chunk_size = 4
first_partition=1
rv = seq[0:first_partition].join(
          [b'A'] * (chunk_size - first_partition))
```

Output:

```
rv = b'AAAAA'
```

Why is rv 5 b'A' values instead of 4?

Comment: For the record, `b'A'` is a `bytes` object, not binary.

Comment: The results would be vastly more understandable if you (at least temporarily) used different characters for the joiner and the joined text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just break it out and look at what you're actually doing:

```
>>> seq[0:first_partition]
b'A'
>>> [b'A'] * (chunk_size - first_partition)
[b'A', b'A', b'A']
```

If you join 3 `A`s with an `A` as a separator, you'll get five `A`s.
Here's an equivalent:

```
>>> '-'.join('OOO')
'O-O-O'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're joining 3 b'A' ([b'A', b'A', b'A']) using b'A' as a separator, so it is b'AAAAA' in result